# Using a different class in a class's DAO

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dao

I am using Hibernate and have a Data Access Object for my Person Entity:

```
public interface PersonDAO extends JpaRepository<Person, String>
{
  Person findById(String id);
  CsFinal findByCsFinal_CsStudentId(String id);
}
```

I know I could make a CsFinal DAO and just call findByCsStudentId, but I am wondering if what I am doing above is possible.  The reason for doing it is I am not sure it is necessary to have a DAO where I will only have one method in the entire DAO.

Edit:  The exception when running the current code:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path []
threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is     
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter 
found capable of converting from type [Person] to type [CsFinal]] with    
root cause


org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter 
found capable of converting from type [Person] to type [CsFinal]
```

Comment: 1. It is fine to have only one method in entire DAO (even no methods, only those coming from hierarchy). 2. Why don't you just try it?

Comment: @Shadov sorry, I forgot to add the exception I was getting.  Went ahead and edited the post.  Seems like the consensus is to have a DAO for each entity regardless of how many methods are in each one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommendation is to use a separate Dao for CsFinal , because when you do a find all or save using the repository class, the save will be done based on the primary key column of Person `JpaRepository<Person, String>`. So if you want to leverage the save functionality you would ideally need to go for a separate repository for each entity class.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  So even if I never plan on making transactions to this particular table it sounds like best practice is to have a DAO for each entity regardless of how many methods or the functionality of the DAO.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, The design should be such that each entity has its own Repository .